# has the tex.sx banner been "simplified"?

Tags: bug, status-norepro, design

i have recently noticed that the banner for tex.sx is missing the beautiful
background.  there used to be some very well chosen examples of tex output
along with the obvious tex logo.

i've checked this with several browsers (firefox, explorer, seamonkey), and
none of them are showing the background.  so either my monitor has gone
(selectively) flaky, or my eyes are playing tricks (again, selectively).

any explanation?

Comment: [This](http://i.stack.imgur.com/5vfkm.png) is what I see as the Meta.TeX.SE banner, and I see [something similar](http://i.stack.imgur.com/QLoME.png) for TeX.SE.

Comment: @Werner -- that looks about the same as what i see -- basically a white background.  i've tried fiddling with the color and contrast settings, but i guess it's back to the systems guys for help.  (since you've provided images, which you wouldn't have if you didn't see something different, i can only assume that my monitor is maladjusted.  thanks.)

Comment: Yes, I can see images in the background...

Comment: Vertical viewing angle can have a major impact on apparent contrast, depending on the display technology used in the monitor. On my laptop, the background image is barely visible when the line of sight is perpendicular to the display. The background vanishes when viewed from above, and clearly becomes visible when viewed from below.

Comment: @mvkorpel -- thanks for this.  however, the monitor i'm (not) seeing this on is a dell desktop 27in wide-screen monitor (screen resolution 2048x1440), adjusted to be plumb-line vertical, centered vertically at eye level.  i've tried looking at it from below, as you suggest, but no change.  absolutely no reason i can conceive of for the problem, but i'm learning to live with it.